# Efficient matrix update and matrix multiplication using Scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix (236680*236680), and my pc does not have sufficient memory to read in the complete matrix so that I am thinking the Scipy sparse matrix. My goal is to multiply a generated matrix (not sparse) by np.eye(the number of observation)-np.ones(the number of observation)/the number of observation with a sparse matrix.

In Scipy, I use the following code, but the computation is still huge. My questions include:

1. to generate the first matrix, is there any other way to speed the process?
2. for the matrix multiplication, is there any way to reduce the memory usage, as the first matrix is not sparse?

-

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
fline=5
nn=1/fline
M=lil_matrix((fline,fline))
M.setdiag(values=1-nn,k=0)
for i in range(fline)[1:]:
    M.setdiag(values=0-nn,k=i)
    M.setdiag(values=0-nn,k=-i)

#the first matrix is:
array([[ 0.8, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2],
       [-0.2,  0.8, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2],
       [-0.2, -0.2,  0.8, -0.2, -0.2],
       [-0.2, -0.2, -0.2,  0.8, -0.2],
       [-0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2,  0.8]])
#the second matrix is:
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [1., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
a2=M.dot(B)
#the final expected results
array([[-0.2,  0. , -0.2,  0.6,  0. ],
       [-0.2,  0. , -0.2, -0.4,  0. ],
       [-0.2,  0. , -0.2,  0.6,  0. ],
       [-0.2,  0. , -0.2, -0.4,  0. ],
       [ 0.8,  0. ,  0.8, -0.4,  0. ]])
```

Updated: is there any way to improve the speed of the cross product? Numpy dot and Scipy sparse dot functions are tested.

Comment: With that off-diagonal fill it's no longer sparse. `scipy.sparse` only saves memory if most of the elements are 0 (e.g 80%).  There are convenience functions/formats for creating a sparse matrix from diagonals, such as `sparse.diags`.  `coo` was the original way of creating these matrices, from 3 arrays, and it is still the most basic input.  Calculations are done with the `csr` format.  Sparse readily converts among these formats, but some conversions take time.

Comment: What is `nn` in the code?

Comment: The code is one part of my implemented algorithm, and nn is to get the values I need in the matrix.

Comment: `but the loop to update the off-diagonal elements is slow.` what kind of operations you need for off-diagonal elements?

Comment: You final/expected matrix does not look sparse. Are you sure you want to use sparse matrix for the task you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy sparse matrix is used, since one of the matrics is a sparse matrix and the cross product function in the sparse matrix is the fastest between Numpy and Scipy.

For the first question, @Tai's answer is the foundation, but I use numpy.full function (a little bit faster).

For the second question, dividing the whole matrix and save smaller computed matrices in files are used.

```
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import vstack
import h5sparse
import numpy as num

fline=236680
nn=1/fline; dd=1-nn; off=0-nn
div=int(fline/(61*10))

for i in range(61*10):
    divM= num.full((fline, div), off) + sparse.identity(fline,format='csc')[:,0+div*i:div+div*i]

    vs=[]
    for j in range(divM.shape[1]):
        divMB=csr_matrix(divM.T[j]).dot(weights)
        vs.append(divMB)
    divapp=vstack(vs)

    if i ==0:
        h5f = h5sparse.File("F:/dissertation/dallastest/temp/tt1.h5")
        h5f.create_dataset('sparse/matrix', data=divapp, chunks=(389,),maxshape=(None,))        
    else:
        h5f['sparse/matrix'].append(divapp)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem: Mathematically,

```
arr1 = array([[ 0.8, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2],
       [-0.2,  0.8, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2],
       [-0.2, -0.2,  0.8, -0.2, -0.2],
       [-0.2, -0.2, -0.2,  0.8, -0.2],
       [-0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2,  0.8]])
```

is equivalent to

```
arr1 = -0.2 * [[1,1,1,1,1,], + 1
               [1,1,1,1,1,],     1
               [1,1,1,1,1,],       1
               [1,1,1,1,1,],         1
               [1,1,1,1,1,]]           1

    = [1] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] * 0.2 + 1
      [1]                           1
      [1]                             1
      [1]                               1
      [1]                                 1
```

Thus, it can be generated using

```
-0.2 * np.outer([1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1]) + scipy.sparse.identity(5)
```

---

For the second problem, let me abuse the notation

```
-0.2* [1] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] @ B + scipy.sparse.identity(5) @ B 
      [1]
      [1]
      [1]
      [1]
```

can be reduced to

```
np.outer([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], B.sum(axis=0)) * -0.2 + scipy.sparse.identity(5) @ B
```

One needs not really compute `np.outer([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], B.sum(axis=0))` as this would be a dense square matrix that the memory may not fit. (Note that the outer product is basically repeats `B.sum(axis=0)` in every row it contains.)

**To recover the results in a memory efficient way**, you only need to store `B.sum(axis=0)` and `scipy.sparse.identity(5) @ B` .

Comment: Thanks for providing the codes. For the large dataset, it is impossible to read the whole matrix in the memory so that dividing the matrix and using some loops are necessary. For example, np.outer([1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1]) must get the memory error in the large data case. My current code involves saving parts of matrices as h5f tables sequentially. After solving some computation bottlenecks, I will post my code.

Comment: @Vicky Iook forward to seeing your work. Yes, doing outer product may would not work. I am not sure your use case of the resulting matrix but you should not need to compute all the results as there are many duplicates of entries. For example, `np.outer([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], B.sum(axis=0))` just repeats `B.sum(axis=0)` in every row.